# Async validation is triggered multiple times on form.setValues()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm using Angular 5, reactive forms approach.

I have a form inside an Angular Material dialog that I am using for both entering and editing data. My constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public documentService: DocumentService, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.createForm();
    if (this.data.edit) {
        this.setValues();
    }
    this.setTitles();
}
```

The `createForm` call creates the reactive form where I have the async validation:

```
createForm() {
    this.documentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        ...
        documentNumber: new FormControl('',
                {
                    updateOn: 'blur',
                    validators: [Validators.required],
                    asyncValidators: [this.checkDocumentNumber.bind(this)]
                }),

        ...
    });
}
```

If the dialog is in 'edit' mode, the `setValues` call patches the data that needs to be edited:

```
setValue() {
    this.form.patchData({
        ...
        documentNumber: this.data.document.documentNumber
        ...
    });
}
```

The `setTitles` call sets the dialog title.

The `checkDocumentNumber` call gets a `boolean` value from the server:

```
checkDocumentNumber(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    const formValue = this.form.value;
    return this.documentService
        .checkDocumentNumber(new Document(this.data.edit ? this.data.document.id : 0,
            form.documentNumber)).pipe(map((response: boolean) => {
            return response ? { inUse: true } : null;
        }));
}
```

The API call made is:

```
checkDocumentNumber(doc: Document) {
    return this.http.post(`/Documents/Inbox/CheckDocumentNumber`, doc);
}
```

The form dialog in 'edit' mode is called like this:

```
this.dialogService.open(DocumentDialogComponent,
    {
        data: {
            edit: true,
            document: this.document
        }
    });
```

The issue I'm having is that when I open the dialog to edit the document data, 9 API calls are made to check the document number. The first 5 are cancelled, then one that returns `200`, another one that is cancelled and finally two more that return `200`.

The same scenario in  a different part of the app gets me 3 cancelled and two `200` calls.

How do I stop angular from making these unnecessary API calls? Before Angular 5, the `updateOn` flag wasn't there so I thought that with that out, this won't be happening.

Here's a screenshot of the API calls being made:

[image: API calls being made]

Comment: The point on updateOn is valid , but the question needs http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . No one but you sees these API calls, and this problem may be specific to your case.

Comment: I just added the API call, it is a simple `post`, that's why I didn't think it is important. I'm also developing the API, but the issue is clearly not there.

Comment: API call is not important. The fact that it is done multiple times is. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve presumes that the problem can be replicated without that unimportant things. Please, provide a way to replicate it, otherwise the question is off-topic.

Comment: All the code related to the question is there. The constructor and how it differs from when the form is used for entering data, the creating of the form, patching the values into the form, making the API call, and I just added a screen shot with the API calls. I'll set up a plunker in a few minutes as well

Comment: Yes, a plunker would be helpful here. Any way, a fix may involve making `checkDocumentNumber` a subject with `debounceTime`, and `asyncValidators` push new values to `this.checkDocumentNumberSubject.next`. Even if the problem with setValue wouldn't be there, usually you never want to let users spam the backend with validation requests.

Comment: This is only happening on the initial dialog open, after that, calls are made only when `blur` is triggered. I'm having a bit of trouble setting up the plunker because of the API (mine isn't live atm), I'll edit as soon as I set it up

Comment: I am running into something similar. I have an async validator and even fields I dont update are triggering my async validator to run. Basically I use patch value to update the form. All I can think is that Im updating the entire form, even the fields that dont change. So I think the field with the async validator is running the validation, when I dont think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use debouncePromise function to reduce the trigger times. It may be caused by the re-render of view.

```js
asyncValidators: [debouncePromise(this.checkDocumentNumber.bind(this))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular performs the request on every value change. The docs specify async validators only if the sync ones pass ["to avoid potentially expensive async validation processes (such as an HTTP request)"](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators)

Here's what I think is happening:

- `updateOn: 'blur'` is for user interaction. It does not apply when you change the value via code.
- You instantiate the form -> the validator is fired, triggering a request.
- You `patchData()` in `setValue()` -> the validator is triggered again.
- I'm guessing Angular internally uses switchMap for the validation Observable, which would explain the cancellations if you changed the value

I don't know how you get to 9 requests, for that I would need to see the full code (@EstusFlask as commented, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

What might help:

- Add some sync validators. `Validators.required` will avoid a request for empty values, including the initial `''`
- Instead of separately patching the default value after creating the form, calculate the default for creation.
  Not needed with `required` in this case where default is empty, but needed in other cases, and I find it cleaner.

  ```
  const defaultDocumentNumber = this.data.edit ? this.data.document.documentNumber : '';
  ...
  documentNumber: new FormControl(defaultDocumentNumber, ...
  ```
- I'm guessing you have other controls in the form that are triggering validation. That might explain how you get to 9 calls.
  If that's the case, you could avoid some validation triggers using `FormControl.patchValue()`'s second parameter `options`, specifically the `emitEvent` and `onlySelf` fields.
  Again, can't really say without a reproducible example. Have a look at the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#patchvalue).

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the underlying issue was that the input was removed from the DOM.
When hiding a field, if it's removed from the DOM, be sure to remove it from the reactive form as well.

Our best guess is Angular retries the AsyncValidator continuously when the form input can't be found.

Answer (score -1):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74369475/19552791) says, the render can be causing multiple triggers on the async validation, i had the same problem and using `debounceTime(1)` to avoid it help me to solve it.

Comment: An explanation of how and why your code works and addresses the question would be ideal. Remember, you are leaving solutions not just for the original asker but for future users, so providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value and make it more likely to attract upvotes. Please [edit] your post and add an explanation.